# Sleeping Barber Problem in Clojure using core/async and go

Tags: clojure

Hello and thank you for any help. I am just starting to learn Clojure, and think its amazing. Below is my codes for the sleeping barber problem. I thought that dropping-buffers from core/async would be perfect for this problem, and while it seems to work it never stops.

The haircuts and dropping buffer seem to work right.

**---Edited**

**It does stop now. But I get an error trying to check customer-num for nil (I've noted the line in the code below). It seems like it can't do an if on a nil because it's nil!**

```
(if (not (nil? customer-num)) ;; throws error => Cannot invoke "clojure.lang.IFn.invoke()" because the return value of "clojure.lang.IFn.invoke(Object)" is null
```

**---End of edit**

Also, how to get the return value of the number of haircuts to the calling operate-shop?

Sleeping barber problem as written up in Seven Languages in Seven Weeks. It was created by Edsger Dijkstra in 1965.

- A barber shop takes customers.
- Customers arrive at random intervals, from ten to thirty milliseconds.
- The barber shop has three chairs in the waiting room.
- The barber shop has one barber and one barber chair.
- When the barber’s chair is empty, a customer sits in the chair, wakes up the barber, and gets a haircut.
- If the chairs are occupied, all new customers will turn away.
- Haircuts take twenty milliseconds.
- After a customer receives a haircut, he gets up and leaves.
- Determine how many haircuts a barber can give in ten seconds.

---

```
(ns sleepbarber
  (:require [clojure.core.async
             :as a
             :refer [>! <! >!! <!! go go-loop chan dropping-buffer close! thread
                     alt! alts! alts!! timeout]]))

(def barber-shop (chan (dropping-buffer 3))) ;; no more than 3 customers waiting

(defn cut-hair []
  (go-loop [haircuts 0]
    (let [customer-num (<! barber-shop)]
       (if (not (nil? customer-num)) ;; throws error => Cannot invoke "clojure.lang.IFn.invoke()" because the return value of "clojure.lang.IFn.invoke(Object)" is null      
        (do (<! (timeout 20))   ;; wait for haircut to finish
            (println haircuts "haircuts!" (- customer-num haircuts) "customers turned away!!")
            (recur (inc haircuts)))
        haircuts))))

(defn operate-shop [open-time]
  ((let [[_ opening] (alts!! [(timeout open-time)
                              (go-loop [customer 0]
                                      (<! (timeout (+ 10 (rand-int 20)))) ;; wait for random arrival of customers
                                      (>! barber-shop customer)
                                      (recur (+ customer 1)))])]
     (close! barber-shop)
     (close! opening)
     )))

(cut-hair)
(operate-shop 2000)
```

Comment: I updated based on helpful feedback from @amalloy, but am still struggling to get it to work right. And to answer the question, yes, sadly, this is my actual code. I plead that I'm just starting with Clojure and it is my first dive into the Lisp world.

Answer (score 2):

Without running your code to confirm my suspicions, I see two problems with your implementation.

The first is that the body of `operate-shop` starts with `((`, which you appear to intend as a grouping mechanism. But of course, in Clojure, `(f x y)` is how you call the function `f` with arguments `x y`. So your implementation calls `alts!`, then calls `close!`, then calls `shutdown-agents` - all intended so far - but then calls the result of `alts!` (which surely is not a function) with two nil arguments. So you should get a ClassCastException once your shop closes. Normally I would recommend just removing the outer parens, but since you're using core.async you should wrap the body in `go`, as in `(go x y z)`. Is this your real code? If you call `alts!` outside of a `go` context, as your snippet suggests, [you can only get a runtime error](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/6ac8ed2a26c67bbc3cc43e4e650f97c984666b0c/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L340).

The second is that your first `go-loop` has no termination condition. You treat `customer-num` as if it were a number, but if the channel is closed, it will be nil: that's how you can tell a channel is closed. Involving it in subtraction should throw some kind of exception. Instead, you should check whether the result is nil, and if so, exit the loop as the shop is closed.